# How to reset a single table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the primary key values to start from 1 again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To reset the index/primary key in SQLite just type:

```
$ rails console
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'yourtablename'")
```

Comment: taking inspiration from your answer... `Person.connection.execute('delete from people' )`        `Person.connection.execute("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name = 'People'" )`

Comment: In case anyone tried this and got an error, I did `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from 'yourtablename'")` and it worked because it would give me an error that said `sqlite_sequence where name = 'yourtablename' is not a valid table name` or something like that.

Answer (score 187):

A lot of people (like me) come here to find how to delete all the data in the table. Here you go:

```
$ rails console

> ModelName.delete_all
```

or

```
> ModelName.destroy_all
```

destroy_all checks dependencies and callbacks, and takes a little longer.
delete_all is a straight SQL query.

More info here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class

Comment: This solution resets the table entries, but not the primary key.

Comment: Yeah this is great -- but I want to the reset the index! Neither delete_all or destroy_all is resetting the index to 1.

Comment: This answer solved the question of the majority users who reached it. That's what really matters. Besides that, It's not the only answer and it's not flagged as the correct one. The author also explained his intention. So I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 51):

I've been using the following from rails console to delete everything in the table and then reset the index counter (Ruby 2 & Rails 4):

```
> ModelName.delete_all
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('plural_model_name')
```

Comment: This worked really well for me, but a small detail is that your `model_name` in the reset command needs to plural, like the actual name of the table NOT the singular name of the model.

Comment: Also works with the symbolic version: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(:plural_model_name)`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 21):

Since Rails 4.2 you can use **[`truncate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9a4e183fe9f81365f7815c391512b3d46622d8c8) directly on an [ActiveRecord connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-truncate)**:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.truncate(:table_name)
```

This **wipes all data** and **resets the autoincrement counters** in the table. Works in MySQL and Postgres, *does not* work in Sqlite.

Answer (score 18):

@khelll's link is helpful. The command you want to truncate one table is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table_name}")
```

Answer (score 10):

Add `gem 'database_cleaner'` to your Gemfile, run `$ bundle install`, and then:

```
> DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :only => ['yourtablename'])
```

You can specify more tables:

```
> DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :only => ['table1', 'table2', 'table3'])
```

If you leave the last parameter out, it will truncate the whole database:

```
> DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) # your database is truncated
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and Sqlite3

Here's what worked for me (taking a bit from all of the above):

```
$ rails c
> ModelName.delete_all
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'table_name'")
```

I was then able to add new records to my table with the index starting back at 1

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this question when the database is Postgres, you can do this from the Rails console:

```
rails console
irb(main):028:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT SETVAL('accounts_id_seq', 1)")
```

Where the `accounts` in the `accounts_id_seq` is the name of the table.