# Reset the id field in a table in a sqlite db in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Im using sqlite db in a sample rails application. From my users table, i have cleared all records using `User.delete_all`. But now whenever i insert a new record in the table using `User.create`, the id is starting at a value which is one more than the id of the last record which was there in the table. For example, if my table had 5 records and i cleared all, then when i do User.create, its starting at id 6. 
Is there any way i can make the id start from 1 again ?

Thank You

Comment: I believe you'd to do a rake db:reset or similar to clear the index. Or, you could use this: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html. However, why do you need to do this??

Comment: Fixed by running the following at rails console : ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'users'")

Answer (score 5):

Similar question : [How to reset a single table in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921074/how-to-reset-a-single-table-in-rails) . We can run the following at rails console to reset id column to 1 for a sqlite table

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = '<table_name>'")
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have autoincrement turned on for the id column.
Sqlite handles these values in an internal table called `sqlite_sequence`. You could reset the id for a particular autoincrement-enabled table by querying:

```
UPDATE "sqlite_sequence" SET "seq" = 0 WHERE "name" = $YOURTABLENAME
```

However, this is not a good idea because the autoincrement functionality is intended to be used in a way that the user does not influence its algorithm. Ideally, you should not care about the actual value of your id but consider it only as a unique identifier for a record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). An alternate way would be to use the active record api from rails console, which is what i did.