# How to reset the primary key id in ruby on rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using rails 6.0.3.4, I am trying to reset the primary key for my table 'users' each time I delete a user.

I tried entering to the rails console and using the command

```
ActiveRecord:: Base. connection. reset_pk_sequence!('users')
```

But I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `reset_pk_sequence!' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x000000000af92360>)
Did you mean?  reset_sequence!
```

I also tried

```
ActiveRecord:: Base. connection. reset_sequence!('users')
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3))
```

In every post i read, the command `reset_pk_sequence!`  seems to work, but for me it doesn´t.

Is there any way I can reset the primary key of my table users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean resetting the auto-increment value to 0?  That's an odd thing to want to do every time you delete a row, it could break referential integrity...

Comment: I agree with @alex, this is not only unnecessary, it could actually break things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset the id field in a table in a sqlite db in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892065/reset-the-id-field-in-a-table-in-a-sqlite-db-in-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method *does* exist (as of Rails 6.0.0) for PostgreSQL:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::SchemaStatements#reset_pk_sequence!`

https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements/reset_pk_sequence%21

Note that you are using SQLite:

`#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x000000000af92360>`

So your available methods are here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SQLite3Adapter.html

More importantly, **YOU SHOULDN'T RESET YOUR TABLE IDS JUST BECAUSE YOU DELETED A USER**.
The database can handle incrementing the IDs no problem, even after you delete a user.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a use-case that would require resetting the Db Ids after deleting a record.

If you REALLY want to do this:
[Reset the id field in a table in a sqlite db in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892065/reset-the-id-field-in-a-table-in-a-sqlite-db-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

The method is [documented as](http://-%20https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-reset_sequence-21):

> `reset_sequence!(table, column, sequence = nil)`
> Set the sequence to the max value of the table's column.

So to reset the default primary key sequence you would do `User.connection.reset_sequence!('users', 'id')`. Well that's if the method actually did something.

However if you look [at the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe76a95b0d252a2d7c25e69498b720c96b243ea2/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L349) this method should actually be implemented by the database adapter:

```
# Set the sequence to the max value of the table's column.
def reset_sequence!(table, column, sequence = nil)
  # Do nothing by default. Implement for PostgreSQL, Oracle, ...
end
```

In the case of SQLite the adapter does not implement the method and it does a whole lot of nothing.

```
irb(main):014:0> User.connection.method(:reset_sequence!).source_location
=> ["/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb", 349]
```

And as noted by @Chiperific YAGNI anyways. But if you insist you can use the answer from [Reset the id field in a table in a sqlite db in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892065/reset-the-id-field-in-a-table-in-a-sqlite-db-in-rails).